# OpenAPI 3.0: Editability of a field - dynamically

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is is possible to set the editability of a field dynamically in openapi 3.0?

The following would be an example of a workaround:

```
    FooBar:
      description: |
        This type defines a type FooBar.
      type: object
      properties:
        myNumber:
          type: EditableNumber
          description: The number that should be editable dynamically.

    EditableNumber:
      description: |
        This type defines an editable number.
      type: object
      properties:
        value:
          type: number
          description: The actual value
        editable:
          type: boolean
          description: whether the field is editable.
      required:
        - value
```

But it would be nicer to do something like this:

```
    FooBar:
      description: |
        This type defines a type FooBar.
      type: object
      properties:
        myNumber:
          type: number
          description: The number that should be editable dynamically.
          readonly: true/false
```

But true/false can not be set dynamically, right?

Or is there any other possibility to do that without the workaround?

Thanks

Comment: What's the actual use case? is this the case where, e.g., a field can be modified via POST but cannot be modified via PATCH?

Comment: The use case is that the consumer of the response should know if a certain field can be modified with a new request or not.